# Tkinter with after and time.sleep

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, sleep

The below python code has a TKinter gui which updates on what's going on in the calculation function (which calls itself at the end with self.after(). The GUI has also some sliders where the user will be able to adjust parameters. The calculation has a sleep delay in it which is the problem: The code works well, except that the time.sleep(1) is blocking not just the calculation for 1 second, but also the GUI itself: It's only possible to move the sliders every second and then everything is blocked for one second. What can I do that the time.sleep(1) only makes the calculation function sleep, but not the GUI itself? Do I need to run the calculation function in a separate thread?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import time

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.i=0
        self.var1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var3 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var4 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var5 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var6 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var7 = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var1,justify='left').pack()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var2).pack()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var3).pack()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var4).pack()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var5).pack()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var6).pack()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var7).pack()


        p1 = tk.Scale(master, from_=1, to=20, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL).pack()
        p2 = tk.Scale(master, from_=1, to=20, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL).pack()
        p3 = tk.Scale(master, from_=1, to=20, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL).pack()
        p4 = tk.Scale(master, from_=1, to=20, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL).pack()
        p5 = tk.Scale(master, from_=1, to=20, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL).pack()

        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal",length=100, mode="determinate")
        self.progress.pack()

    def calculation(self):
        # complex calculations that last 30 minutes in total
        self.i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        max=1000
        self.var1.set("Value1: "+str(self.i))
        self.var2.set("Value2: "+str(self.i+100))
        self.var3.set("Value3: "+str(self.i+100))
        self.var4.set("Value4: "+str(self.i+100))
        self.var5.set("Value5: "+str(self.i+100))
        self.var6.set("Value6: "+str(self.i+100))
        self.var7.set("Value7: "+str(self.i+100))
        self.progress["value"] = int(round(self.i*100/max))
        #self.update()  # no need, will be automatic as mainloop() runs
        self.after(1, self.calculation)

app=GUI()
app.calculation()  # start calculations
app.mainloop()  # run gui
```

Comment: Why do you need `time.sleep(1)` ? Why cannot you have self.after handle the amount of time to be idle instead?

Comment: And you will need update_idletasks....

Comment: In this example yes, but the real code is more complex and sleep is necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use sleep, then yes, the calculation should be done in another thread or another process.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely necessary. Also the real life calculation will last more than one minute. Would I simply call the mainloop with one thread and the calculation with the other thread?

Comment: @Nicolas: yes. You must be sure that the other thread diesn't call any widget methods. You'll have to put the result on a queue and have the gui thread read the result from the queue.

Comment: Do you have any additional info how this queue system works? Thanks

Comment: @Nicolas: start by searching this site.